# Understanding Count pairs in array whose sum is divisible by K

Tags: java, algorithm

I am going through this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-in-array-whose-sum-is-divisible-by-k/) and came across the code for count of pairs divisible by k.

The approach used is:

> An efficient approach is to use Hashing technique. We will separate
> elements into buckets depending on their (value mod K). When a number
> is divided by K then the remainder may be 0, 1, 2, upto (k-1). So take
> an array say freq[] of size K (initialized with Zero) and increase the
> value of freq[A[i]%K] so that we can calculate the number of values
> giving remainder j on division with K.

Below is the code for it:

```
public static int countKdivPairs(int A[], int n, int K) 
    { 
        // Create a frequency array to count 
        // occurrences of all remainders when 
        // divided by K 
        int freq[] = new int[K]; 
  
        // Count occurrences of all remainders 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            ++freq[A[i] % K]; 
  
        // If both pairs are divisible by 'K' 
        int sum = freq[0] * (freq[0] - 1) / 2; 
  
        // count for all i and (k-i) 
        // freq pairs 
        for (int i = 1; i <= K / 2 && i != (K - i); i++) 
            sum += freq[i] * freq[K - i]; 
        // If K is even 
        if (K % 2 == 0) 
            sum += (freq[K / 2] * (freq[K / 2] - 1) / 2); 
        return sum; 
    }
```

I understood the code flow line by line, but I did not understand how this logic in code is solving the problem statement.

Why we are doing these steps:

```
1) int sum = freq[0] * (freq[0] - 1) / 2; 
2) sum += freq[i] * freq[K - i]; 
3)             if (K % 2 == 0) 
                sum += (freq[K / 2] * (freq[K / 2] - 1) / 2);
```

Can you please provide an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is to find all the pairs whose sum is divisible by K.

### Little background:

Hypothetically, assume that the pair `(a, b)` is one of those. So we have

```
(a + b) % K == 0
```

Lets assume:

```
a % K = p
b % K = q
```

where p & q could be any positive integers between `[0, K-1]`.

But the important point is: do you think there is a relationship between p & q?

Yes, there is; because `a+b % K == 0`

```
a = xK + p
b = yK + q

**a + b = (x+y)K + (p+q)**

But we already know that a+b is divisible by K.
That clearly means:

p + q = K or p + q = 0 (remember that both p, q is within [0, K-1])
```

### Back to your question:

```
1) int sum = freq[0] * (freq[0] - 1) / 2; 
2) sum += freq[i] * freq[K - i]; 
3)             if (K % 2 == 0) 
                sum += (freq[K / 2] * (freq[K / 2] - 1) / 2);
```

So the above loop is simply trying to find all the possible pairs with remainders `p` and `K-p` for p in [0, K-1]

Comment: I understood background clearly. Thanks for explanation. But `Back to your question` can you explain more, why we have to multiple in step 2. why step 1, and step3 are like that and why we have an if condition in step 3.

Comment: Bucket: `freq[i] (say B1)`  is the number of items which have a remainder `i`. Similarly `freq[K-i] (say B2)`. Now each of the items from B1 can form a pair with each item from B2. So all the possible valid pairs would be |B1| x |B2|

Comment: The step3 is just to ensure you dont do double-counting

Comment: perfect. Now why we have `/2` in step 1 and step 3?

Comment: The step1 is special. Its meant for `B0`, i.e. all items with `remainder = 0`. As you can rightly imagine, all valid pairs from B0 would be all pairs in B0 (since all items in B0 have remainder = 0)

Comment: My doubt was why it is not B0 * B0? But B0 * (B0 -1) /2? can you please explain

Comment: That's `nc2`.. Number of ways you can choose 2 items from N items. `nc2 = n*(n-1)/2`